# Flink Streaming java.lang.Exception: Could not load the task's invokable class

Tags: java, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to run a basic Flink streaming job (in java) locally. When I run my application using eclipse, it works like a charm. But when I run using Flink command-line interface, I get the following exception

```
10/29/2015 11:15:54 Grouped Aggregation -> (Map -> Stream Sink,Stream Sink)(7/8) switched to SCHEDULED
10/29/2015 11:15:54 Grouped Aggregation -> (Map -> Stream Sink, Stream Sink)(7/8) switched to DEPLOYING
10/29/2015 11:15:54 Grouped Aggregation -> (Map -> Stream Sink, Stream Sink)(8/8) switched to SCHEDULED
10/29/2015 11:15:54 Grouped Aggregation -> (Map -> Stream Sink, Stream Sink)(8/8) switched to DEPLOYING
10/29/2015 11:15:54 Custom Source -> Flat Map -> Map(5/8) switched to    FAILED
java.lang.Exception: Could not load the task's invokable class.
at    org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.loadAndInstantiateInvokable(Tas k.java:696)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:450)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
at   org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.loadAndInstantiateInvokable(Tas    k.java:693)
... 2 more

10/29/2015 11:15:54 Custom Source -> Flat Map -> Map(2/8) switched to   FAILED
java.lang.Exception: Could not load the task's invokable class.
at      org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.loadAndInstantiateInvokable(Tas    k.java:696)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:450)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
at     org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.loadAndInstantiateInvokable(Tas    k.java:693)
... 2 more
```

I am running the Flink-Kafka integration example at:
[data-artisans](http://data-artisans.com/kafka-flink-a-practical-how-to/)

Comment: Which version of the [tag:java] JDK are you using from the command line for compilation and which version are you using in [tag:eclipse] for compilation?

Comment: I use Java 1.8 for both cases.

Comment: Can you try upgrading to 60?

Comment: Hi Eric, I have tried to update my Java to 1.8.0_65 which I thing is the latest version but the problem still exists.

Comment: What command line command are you using to run the app?

Comment: I use **flink run ~/Documents/workspace/projects/flink.jar**

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered on the Flink mailing list: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Could-not-load-the-task-s-invokable-class-td3336.html

The problem was that the jar of the Flink program was build using Eclipse. The user was able to build a working jar using Maven.